# Powershell dialog box with countdown and option to press cancel?

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to create a `Powershell` script that performs the following

1. Shows a dialog box that an update is about to occur
2. Provide a countdown of say 30 seconds
3. During the countdown, a user can press "Cancel Update"
4. If the countdown expires and "Cancel Update" was **not** pressed, then update will occur

Right before the loop, the window shows if I call `$Counter_Form.ShowDialog()` and I can click the Cancel button. When clicking, the following should occur.

1. Window should close after pressing the button. This is **correct**.
2. `$cancel` should be set to `$true` to indicate that Cancel was pressed. However, it remains `$false` and this is **incorrect**. Why is this?

Now, for the problems in the `while` loop

1. The window refreshes to show the new delay, but I cannot click "Cancel Update" since it just shows an hourglass icon and seems to be frozen

Script

```
#Adjust delay here
$delay = 5

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$Counter_Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Counter_Form.Text = "Warning"

#Form size options
$Counter_Form.Width = 350
$Counter_Form.Height = 150

#Centers form on screen
$Counter_Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

#Places form on top of everything else
$Counter_Form.TopMost = $true

$Counter_Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Counter_Label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label

#Label2's text
$Counter_Label2.Text = "Please save all your work"

#Labels size and position
$Counter_Label.AutoSize = $true
$Counter_Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50,60)
$Counter_Label2.AutoSize = $true
$Counter_Label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(90,30)

$cancel = $false
$button1 =  New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button1.Text = "Cancel Update";
$button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(130,80)
$button1.Add_Click({ $Counter_Form.Close(); $cancel = $true})

$Counter_Form.Controls.Add($Counter_Label)
$Counter_Form.Controls.Add($Counter_Label2)
$Counter_Form.Controls.Add($button1)

#LOOP!

while ($delay -ge 0 -And $cancel -eq $false)
{

$Counter_Form.Show()
#Timer label's text
  $Counter_Label.Text = "Update will occur in $($delay) seconds."

  
  start-sleep 1
  $delay -= 1
}

$Counter_Form.Close()
```

Comment: FoxDeploy wrote up a great guide about building a GUI in PowerShell, and how to work around the hourglass issue that you're encountering. Check it our [here](https://www.foxdeploy.com/2016/05/17/part-v-powershell-guis-responsive-apps-with-progress-bars).

Answer (score 0):

For the first question about `$cancel` not being updated to `$true`, it is a result of scope.

Add the `script` scope, with `$script:cancel = $true`. So that line of code should be:

`$button1.Add_Click({ $Counter_Form.Close(); $script:cancel = $true})`

I didn't find an exact solution to what I started. A pieced together some code from various sources and found the following worked. I'm posting it here in case it ends up helping someone:

```
function ShowMsg ($timeout, $message)
{
Add-Type -AssemblyName system.windows.forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName system.drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Window Title"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,300)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.label
$label.Text = $message
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,205)
$form.Controls.Add($label)

#add button to form
$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(160,215)
$okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,23)
$okButton.Text = 'Cancel Update'
$okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $okButton
$form.Controls.Add($okButton)

$cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$cancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(40,215)
$cancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,23)
$cancelButton.Text = 'Allow Update'
$cancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::CANCEL

$form.CancelButton = $cancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($cancelButton)

$timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$timer.Interval = $timeout * 1000
$timer.add_tick({$form.Close()})
$timer.Start()

$form.Topmost = $true
$form.ShowDialog()

$form.Dispose()
}
```

Calling the function:

```
$timeout = 60 #seconds
$message_response = ShowMsg -timeout $timeout -message "Hello, update is happening"
```